# How to test java.net.http (Java 11) requests BodyPublisher?

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client

I'm trying to test my code which uses the new Java 11 [`java.net.http.HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html).

In my production code I have something like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = ... (gets injected)

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://localhost:1234"))
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray("example".getBytes()))
        .build();

return httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
```

And in my test I mock the `HttpClient` and so get the [`java.net.http.HttpRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html). How do I get/test its request body (= my `"example"`)? I can call `request.bodyPublisher()` to get a `HttpRequest.BodyPublisher`, but then I'm stuck.

- I've tried to cast it to `jdk.internal.net.http.RequestPublishers.ByteArrayPublisher` (which it actually is), but it won't compile because the corresponding package is not exported by the module.
- I've checked the available methods in the `HttpRequest.BodyPublisher`-interface (`.contentLength()`, `.subscribe(subscriber)`) but I guess it's not possible with them.
- I've tried to just create a new `BodyPublisher` and compare them using `.equals()`, but there is no real implementation of it and so the comparison was always false.

Comment: The request `body` is an input to the `HttpRequest` you're trying to make. Which itself should be ideally something that you a user should provide, not the other way round, that the `HttpRequest` provides you the body. Is there something else that I am missing in your question?

Comment: True, in my production code I put the `body` into the `HttpRequest` (see first block of code). But in my **test**, I'd like to verify that the correct `body` has been set in the request - thus getting it out again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are interested in how body will look like in handler you can know it with help of HttpRequest.BodyPublisher Subscriber. We call `subscription.request` in order to receive all body items and collect them.

Our custrom subscriber:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Flow;

public class FlowSubscriber<T> implements Flow.Subscriber<T> {
    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private List<T> bodyItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<T> getBodyItems() {
        try {
            this.latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return bodyItems;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
        //Retrieve all parts
        subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T item) {
        this.bodyItems.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        this.latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        this.latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Usage in the test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    byte[] expected = "example".getBytes();

    HttpRequest.BodyPublisher bodyPublisher =
            HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(expected);

    FlowSubscriber<ByteBuffer> flowSubscriber = new FlowSubscriber<>();
    bodyPublisher.subscribe(flowSubscriber);

    byte[] actual = flowSubscriber.getBodyItems().get(0).array();

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Looks terribly complicated but seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, but "as designed". There is interesting library for testing httpclient
https://github.com/PGSSoft/HttpClientMock

Comment: The use of `CountDownLatch` here is curious: I would advise using a `CompletableFuture<List<T>>` instead - as this doesn't force you back into a synchronous API and makes it possible to relay any exception received by `onError` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok using a simple dependency, see [HttpClientMock](https://github.com/PGSSoft/HttpClientMock).

For your example, you'd mock and verify that request like:

```java
// Given
httpClientMock
  .onPost("http://localhost:1234")
  .withBody(is("example"))
  .doReturn(200, "ok");

// When
/* call your function here */

// Then
httpClientMock
  .verify()
  .post("http://localhost:1234")
  .withBody(is("example"))
  .called(1);
```

I had a reason to do this with an OpenAPI generated client that used the JDK 11 HttpClient, and spent a few hours trying to "do it the right way" but it only took a few minutes to get the HttpClientMock way going.

I detailed a lot more details on my experience in this gist: https://gist.github.com/booniepepper/6fe970e1de28f975887a5e7af8a2cd8b